# How does the pattern of assigning `@State` in `onReceive` ensure that view state is in sync?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm having a little trouble with the following pattern which integrates Combine publishers into SwiftUI so that view state is updated when publishers emit:

```swift
struct ItemList: View {
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<[Item], Never>
    @State private var items = [Item]()

    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            ItemRow(item: item)
        }
        .onReceive(publisher) {
            items = $0
        }
    }
}
```

[Above example from Swift by Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/observing-combine-publishers-in-swiftui-views/)

I feel like I'm missing something when I read it.

Let's assume you initialize `items` to the correct (at that time) value. What ensures that the published value won't change between the creation of `ItemList` and the first call to `body`, where it first starts listening to changes? Or if there is no such guarantee, then what else is preventing the view from ending up in the wrong initial state because of this?

Comment: It won't matter how many times a values has been emitted by the publisher when this view loads. It will always load with an empty array and will be forced to redraw when items change to a new value.

Comment: @cora Thanks for the input. Although my question is about the case where we assume that "you initialize items to the correct (at that time) value" — not an empty array — if I understand you correctly you're confirming that the view will end up in an inconsistent state with regards to the published value (i.e. what you actually intend: always in sync with the published value). That makes me question why I've seen this pattern in multiple places...

Comment: He does add that this is a special case after the code example. It would be safer to take the more general approach of designing an observable view model and redraw the view after it’s published properties get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a [`NavigationLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink):

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: { ItemList(publisher: myPub) },
    label: { Text("Show List") }
)
```

Here we have a case where SwiftUI creates the `ItemList` immediately, but doesn't ask the `ItemList` for its `body` until the user taps the link.

(How do we know it creates the `ItemList` immediately? [The `destination` argument is not declared `@escaping`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:label:)-27n7s), so SwiftUI has to call it inside the `NavigationLink` initializer.)

So in fact there is a real risk in this case that `items` should change between when the `ItemList` is created and when it appears on screen.

We solve this by using a publisher like [`CurrentValueSubject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject#) that publishes its current value immediately to each new subscriber. That way, it doesn't matter how much later SwiftUI decides to use the view. As soon as SwiftUI uses the view, it subscribes to the publisher and immediately gets the current value. SwiftUI can handle that update before updating the framebuffer, so the user doesn't see a flash of incorrect data.

Comment: Thank you for writing up an interesting example. Using `CurrentValueSubject` is a solution that I've come to as well, but the problem I see is that I often don't know which kind of publisher is handed to me by a framework or that it's implied that it doesn't matter (like in the example where we have `AnyPublisher`). This seems to make it difficult to determine correctness when reading a view that uses this pattern. It seems to me that the user of the view also has to know this detail now, unless you constrain injection to current value subjects

Answer (score 0):

We need to read it in sequence:

1. State is initiailzed, supposing `items = [Item1, Item2, Item3]`
2. `body` is called to render view
3. `List` is constructed with current items, ie. `List([Item1, Item2, Item3])`
4. `onReceive` is called on constructed `List of 3)` and creates view around  that list with subscriber to publisher
5. subscriber requests current events from publisher
6. if there are events in publisher then onReceive's closure handler is called (see below) otherwise no changes and `List of 3)` is shown on screen

   6.1. if handler gets same initial `[Item1, Item2, Item3]` (subscriber extracts all available items) then state is not changed and `List of 3)` is shown on screen

   6.2. if handler gets different items `[ItemX, ItemY]` then state change invalidates view and List is rebuilt with `[ItemX, ItemY]` which are shown on screen (there is no cycling because refresh is synchronous and we get into 6.1 at second pass).

That's simplified logic of provided code snapshot.

Comment: Thank you. While your list corresponds to my understanding and thus my reason for thinking I've missed something, it doesn't address the question directly. It does still imply that if the published value changes between 1 and 4 then the view will be in an unintended state with regards to it though, which should reasonably translate to that this pattern is a bug.

Comment: it cannot (well it can, but not in this pass/event) - this sequence is synchronous - it works with current thread view/publisher states, in a fact it is UI thread. If a publisher is not thread-safe it is a problem of publisher, I do not consider buggy environments.

Comment: It sounds like you have an idea of some details that I've missed! Feel free to write an answer based on that — it is the question after all.

Comment: More specifically, I think I'm missing what makes it illegal for arbitrary time to pass between #1 and #2.

Comment: It is in fact possible for arbitrary time to pass, depending on the context in which you create the `ItemList`. See my answer.